# Objective C++ block semantics

Tags: objective-c, block, objective-c++

Consider the following C++ method:

```
class Worker{
....
private Node *node
};

void Worker::Work()
{
    NSBlockOperation *op=[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:  ^{
            Tool hammer(node);
            hammer.Use();
          }];
    ....
    }
```

What, exactly, does the block capture when it captures "node"?  The language specification for blocks, http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html, is clear for other cases:

> Variables used within the scope of the compound statement are bound to the Block in the normal manner with the exception of those in automatic (stack) storage. Thus one may access functions and global variables as one would expect, as well as static local variables. [testme]
>
> Local automatic (stack) variables referenced within the compound statement of a Block are imported and captured by the Block as const copies.

But here, do we capture the current value of **this**?  A copy of **this** using Worker’s copy constructor?  Or a reference to the place where **node** is stored?

In particular, suppose we say

```
 {
 Worker fred(someNode);
 fred.Work();
 }
```

The object fred may not exist any more when the block gets run.  What is the value of **node**? (Assume that the underlying Node objects live forever, but Workers come and go.)

If instead we wrote

```
void Worker::Work()
    {
        Node *myNode=node;
        NSBlockOperation *op=[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:  ^{
                Tool hammer(myNode);
                hammer.Use();
              }];
        ....
        }
```

is the outcome different?

Comment: consider C++11 lambdas for superior capturing semantics of C++ types.

Comment: @justin: how is it any superior? A C++ lambda would also capture `this` by value and have the exact same semantics.

Comment: @newacct i never wrote "consider C++11 lambdas for superior capturing semantics of `this`". however, a difference is that `this` is **not** implicitly captured with lambdas, which is a good safeguard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html):

> In general you can use C++ objects within a block. Within a member
>   function, references to member variables and functions are via an
>   implicitly imported `this` pointer and thus appear mutable. There are
>   two considerations that apply if a block is copied:
>
> - If you have a __block storage class for what would have been a
>     stack-based C++ object, then the usual copy constructor is used.
> - If
>     you use any other C++ stack-based object from within a block, it must
>     have a const copy constructor. The C++ object is then copied using
>     that constructor.

Empirically, I observe that it const copies the `this` pointer into the block. If the C++ instance pointed to by `this` is no longer at that address when the block executes (for instance, if the Worker instance on which `Worker::Work()` is called was stack-allocated on a higher frame), then you will get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS or worse (i.e. pointer aliasing). So it appears that:

- It is capturing `this`, not copying instance variables by value.
- Nothing is being done to keep the object pointed to by `this` alive.

Alternately, if I reference a locally stack-allocated (i.e. declared in this stack frame/scope) C++ object, I observe that its copy constructor gets called when it is initially captured by the block, and then again whenever the block is copied (for instance, by the operation queue when you enqueue the operation.)

To address your questions specifically:

> But here, do we capture the current value of `this`? A copy of this using Worker’s copy constructor? Or a reference to the place where node is stored?

We capture `this`. Consider it a const-copy of an `intptr_t` if that helps.

> The object `fred` may not exist any more when the block gets run. What is the value of `node`? (Assume that the underlying Node objects live forever, but Workers come and go.)

In this case, `this` has been captured by-value and `node` is effectively a pointer with the value `this + <offset of node in Worker>` but since the Worker instance is gone, it's effectively a garbage pointer.

I would infer no magic or other behavior other than exactly what's described in those docs.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, when you write an instance variable `node`, without explicitly writing `something->node`, it is implicitly `this->node`. (Similar to how in Objective-C, if you write an instance variable `node`, without explicitly writing `something->node`, it is implicitly `self->node`.)

So the variable which is being used is `this`, and it is `this` that is captured. (Technically `this` is described in the standard as a separate expression type of its own, not a variable; but for all intents and purposes it acts as an implicit local variable of type `Worker *const`.) As with all non-`__block` variables, capturing it makes a `const` copy of `this`.

Blocks have memory management semantics when they capture a variable of Objective-C object pointer type. However, `this` does not have Objective-C object pointer type, so nothing is done with it in terms of memory management. (There is nothing that *can* be done in terms of C++ memory management anyway.) So yes, the C++ object pointed to by `this` could be invalid by the time the block runs.